# Application Service Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Criei um aplicativo de serviço no Visual Studio 2015, para poder iniciar
o serviço precisei criar um instalador.

Criei um projeto Visual Studio Installer, preenchi os parâmetros e tudo funcionou.

Só que agora preciso usar o mesmo aplicativo no mesmo servidor só com o nome da instancia diferente, no Visual Studio Installer não encontrei alguma opção de mudar o nome da instancia na hora da instalação.

Existe essa opção? Caso não existem algum aplicativo de instalação gratuito que
permita a mudança do nome da instancia antes de instalar o serviço?

Comment: Você tentou mudar o nome do serviço nas propriedades do serviceInstaller ?

Comment: É serviço do windows ? você quer mudar o nome do serviço? pode posta como esta isso?

Comment: Isso serviço do Windows. Vou postar aqui talvez ajude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GOKU, click com o botão direito em cima do projeto principal e em propriedades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você entrar na propriedades irá abrir essa aba para você. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente mudar o nome do seu assembly e de seu namespace talvez resolva.

E também você pode ira na propriedade do ser objeto serviceInstaller e tentar mudar o nome. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente fazer esses ajustes build novamente o projeto e veja se consegue resolver o seu problema.

Para você instalar um serviço do Windows, se você quiser não precisa criar um instalador. Você pode instalar direto pelo cmd. Segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]